# Controlling Relay with FPGA

Tags: fpga, relay

My proposal for a final project.

> My uncle is making his own smoke house, and to make the smoke he
>   decided on using a water heater element. Over the Thanksgiving holiday
>   we were discussing this, and it gave me the idea for my final project.
>   So, my final project will be creating a controller/display for a water
>   heating element. The goal is to use the DE0 to control the power
>   source to the heating element, so that the wood chips used for
>   smoking, will burn and smoke but not catch fire.
>
> Thermocouples will be connected between a DE0 (on the GPIO header) and
>   the water heating element. The DE0 will read and display (the later on
>   a 16x2 LCD add-on) the temperature of the heating element. The power
>   source for the heating element will be connected to a relay and the
>   control of the relay will be connected to the 5v pin on the DE0’s GPIO
>   header. Upon flipping a switch on the DE0, a LED light will turn on,
>   indicating that power is being sent to the relay and that the element
>   has power. Once the heating element has reached the desired
>   temperature a 15-minute timer will start. This timer will be displayed
>   on the LCD. Once this 15 minutes has passed, the 5-volt signal going
>   to the relay will be cut, the LED turned off, and a new timer will be
>   set for 15 minutes. Once this 15 minutes has passed, the heating
>   element will be given power and upon hitting the desired temperature a
>   15-minute ON timer will be set. This sequence will be repeated until
>   the original switch is flipped off, or until 4 ON-cycles have passed.

As for reading the temperature of the thermocouples I have found that I will require a digitize of sort. This is what I have picked out, [MAX31855](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=MAX31855PMB1%23-ND). My concern is the relay. I am not sure if I am understanding the terminology correct.

What I need is the 5v GPIO of the DEO to send the 5 volts to the relay when called. I am correct in thinking that this particular relay requires 5 volts to turn on and can pass upto 220volts?

http://www.jameco.com/z/TC-5VDC-C14-5-VOLT-2-AMP-8-PIN-DOUBLE-POLE-DOUBLE-THROW-DPDT-RELAY_2158338.html

If I am correct, is there anything special I should know about hooking up it at the FPGA?

Lastly, does anyone have a recommendation of relay for my needs?

Comment: You can't directly drive a relay from a FPGA unless its an SSR. There are many resources online on how to do this.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the DE0 pins are 3.3V logic level, not 5V.  The MAX31855 is also 3.3V only, which is good as it will make interfacing with the DE0 easier (but remember to power it from 3.3V not 5V!).

Comment: To make it easier, you should concentrate on your design rather than finding individual components, I would suggest the Relay board like this one: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-3V-3-3V-Relay-High-Level-Driver-Relay-Module-Module-optocouplefor-Arduino-br-/221887500776?hash=item33a98691e8:g:5JMAAOSwgZ1XqUiT it has an opto-coupler and you can drive it form your board without any problems since it is designed for 3.3V.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that you need 5 Volts for the relay *however* you are going also need to source ~30mA to turn on the coil.

Coil voltage: 5VDC 
Coil Resistance: 178 Ohms

V=I*R = I=V/R   5vdc/178ohms=0.028Amps

If you have a 5 volt power source you could use it to power the relay; and then control a transistor with your FPGA to open and close the low side of the relay circuit.

Comment: my FPGA has a 5v GPIO, wouldn't that work?

Comment: I just realized that the relay of the OP was electromagnetic. I've been reading that the solid state relays do not require a current limiting resistor or transistor.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AQ2AD1-3-28VDC/255-3774-ND/645926

Comment: A quick search I found http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electric-works/AQ2AD1-3-28VDC/255-3774-ND/645926   This solid state relay uses a phototransistor so you still need a current limiting resistor for the LED and about 14mA to light it.